# How does digital signal is propogated in channel?

Tags: digital-communications, telecommunications, digital-modulation

[image: Digital signal transmitted through wireless channel]

As mentioned on the picture a digital signal is sent, after that it got affected by noise and disturbances and it is retrieved perfectly by the repeaters.
My question is, signal in digital is sent as electromagnetic wave right? So it is a Sinusoid, so is it a sinusoid with fixed amplitude or fixed frequency, if it is so; then in the picture shows digital pulse shape is kind of lost its shape, so how I imagine this distortion in terms of sinusoids.

For example: if I send an analog signal, it faded and AWGN added into it I can imagine the distorted analog signal, but I am having difficult time visualizing digital signal distortion from this picture, because we don't send digital pulse in space? Because waves in real life are Sinusoidal. Clarify me like I am five

Comment: The repeater does not use linear amplification to regenerate the pulse. It simply needs to decide whether or not a pulse exists at the input, and if so, generate a fresh, clean pulse at the output. Sometimes [adaptive equalization](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equalization_(communications)) (the "inverse filter" that @dgreenheck mentions) is used to enhance the robustness of the pulse detection.

Answer (score 1):

OK you are five years old.  Have you heard the crack of lightning far away in the distance in the rain? This is a pulse with white noise of the rain. Unlike the visual signature in the image shown, we can hear over a very wide range like microscopic detail. Our ears work like many tuning forks called the cilia (which work like an fast fourier transform).

We recognize the sound of thunder by its signature sound even if it is distorted with echos and the sound of rain. Why? Because we know how it sounds different from all other sounds, we match our expectations to the shape of this wave we hear. If it matches close enough we say we hear thunder.

So what is close enough?  It is called a "match" when most of what we hear matches what we expect only by experience. It almost sounds like a home run sound of a bat hitting a ball but different. So we remember this sound as a signature and align it with our experience.

If we measure it's properties with frequencies, delays and amplitudes we can make a signature filter than matches the wave to optimize the signal and reduce the noise. This is called a "Matched receiver".

It is an ideal match to this input wave in that they have the identical frequency properties so that this signal is boosted while other signatures are lowered.

So it is our experience that shapes our ability to detect this pulse of thunder and the best experience is a receiver that perfectly matches the frequency of the wave generated then conjugates the delay of the channel (air) of each frequency so they arrive undistorted, then we normalize the amplitude (AGC) and multiply it with our experience (integrating cross-correlation filter) to maximize our perception with the minimum error rate ( optimal coherent demodulation of carrier with optimal discrimination with guard bands with feed-forward error detection and correction to improve redundancy ) oops I forgot you are only 5.

Answer (score 0):

It's not just one wave. It's a bunchbof waves of all frequecies, all together forming the pulse. But in transmission line the signal is not an electromagnetic wave (at least when we don't discuss microwave and higher frequencies), but current or voltage waves. Alltogether they are related and propagate together, and are affected by all kinds of things: magnetic, electric, poor design.

Answer (score 0):

The electromagnetic waves are sinusoidal, but there isn't just a single frequency sine wave being transmitted; it is the summation of an infinite number of sinusoids that gives the pulse shape.

But to answer why the signal distortion looks like that, you have to think of how signals are transmitted. As transmission distance increases, the resistance of the transmission cable will increase as well as the parasitic capacitance. You can model this to the first order with a simple RC low-pass filter

[image]

Simulation of this gives the typical capacitor charging/discharge waveform shown below, which match closely with your picture.

[image]

So as you increase R1 or C1, you will see more and more attenuation. In many communications systems, they try to estimate how the channel filtered the signal. The inverse of the channel filter is computed and applied to the received signal to recover the original signal. This gets extremely complicated, but that's the general idea.

Comment: So when we modulate a digital signal to analog and then transmit Via wireless channel, which of course are sinusoids, what is the distortion like, in comparison to the picture?

Comment: What type of channel are you considering? Is it indoor? Outdoor? Is there a line of sight path or not? All of these will affect how the signal is distorted.

Comment: @ZahidulAmin You should get a copy of Proakis (you can find it online if you look hard enough) if you are interested in how digital signals are transmitted in wireless channels and the different types of distortion that can affect the signal.

Answer (score 0):

If we are talking about propagation of a signal in a channel then we are talking an em wave and the transport, be it coax or twisted pair will muddy the signal as shown.

What you are mistakingly believing is that an em wave is a pure sinusoid. On this occasion it is a pulse that will comprise a base sinusoid and a series of harmonics of that base sine wave. It's still a pulse in the time domain but its spectrum comprises harmonics that all get affected differently in the channel. Hence the distortion.

Answer (score 0):

Regeneration involved the desired but weakened pulse energy, and the thermal noise of all the electrons in all the pieces of metal thru which the pulse passes.
The (thermal noise) will confuse the regenerator, particularly as to when to turn on and when to turn off. This will be jitter.

With enough thermal noise, the pulse may become of zero width, unregenerated.